# Trying to get a variable into an addListener function which is run inside a loop

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to get a variable into an addListener function which is run inside a loop, but it always only takes notice of the last instance of the loop variable.

e.g.

```
for(var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
    points[i] = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(data[i].lat), parseFloat(data[i].lng));
    gmarkers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: points[i],
        title: locationdata[i].title
    });
    gmarkers[i].setMap(map);
    bubbles[i] = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: locationdata[i].summary
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(gmarkers[i], 'click', function() {
        alert(i);
        bubbles[i].open(map, gmarkers[i]);
    });
}
```

So the problem is that near the bottom the alert(i) is always the data.length's last item, which makes sense, but I don't know how to correct this.

---

Rocket answered this question and was correct, but the syntax was slightly off, so posting here what the real syntax was for anyone that comes across this later on:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(gmarkers[i], 'click', (function(i) {
    return function() {
        alert(i);
        bubbles[i].open(map, gmarkers[i]);
    }})
(i));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic issue in JavaScript.  You need to make a closure for each of the listeners.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(gmarkers[i], 'click', (function(i) {
    return function(){
        alert(i);
        bubbles[i].open(map, gmarkers[i]);
    };
})(i));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that throws the following error: missing ; before statement

Comment: @hsmoore.com: Whoops, typo.  Try it now :-P

Answer (score 0):

Yet another question that [Frame.js](https://github.com/bishopZ/Frame.js) was designed to solve. Here is a more readable and scalable solution using Frame:

```
for(var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
    Frame(function(next, i){
        google.maps.event.addListener(gmarkers[i], 'click', function() {
            alert(i);
        });
        next();
    }, i);
}
Frame.init();
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is to put your addListener function in another function, and call that in the loop. As Rocket said in his answer it is a question of closures which can be a huge issue if you don't understand it. I am not saying that I do, but I have tried a couple of things and I like it better when you use a seperate method like so:

```
function addEventListener(i){
    google.maps.event.addListener(gmarkers[i], 'click', function() {
        alert(i);
        bubbles[i].open(map, gmarkers[i]);
    });
}
```

But it is just a matter of personal preference. Just thought I'd throw in the other option as well :)